# C++ copy formatted code to word (like Visual assist's)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ms-word, copy-paste, visual-assist

I've browsed but could not find an answer..
I'm trying to copy code from my editor to look like the VA coloring, but it only copies like the VS coloring..
(Another great option would be to somehow do it like StackOverflow formats, but I could not find how to do that as well)
I've found:
http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/rtf.asp

But it does not show where it is, nor can I find it (VS 2010)..
Does anyone know how to do it? 
Or does anyone has an idea on how to copy formatted code to word?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but,

> **Microsoft Visual Studio**
>
> Copying HTML to the clipboard is a built-in feature of Microsoft Visual Studio and Visual 
>   Assist X **does not enhance the feature**. The clipboard contains only the **default** colors of 
>   the IDE. Enhanced syntax colors are not placed in the clipboard.

The feature you've meant was available only at Visual C++ 6.0.

VC++ 6.0 has no embedded ability to copy formatted code so they made their own realization of this feature in their plugin.

---

If you want just have VAssistX colored pdf you can try to print document in Visual Studio using any pdf printer such as PDFCreator then you can import it in Word (at least in LibreOffice Writer).

Answer (score 0):

A quote from the page you linked to:

Microsoft Visual Studio
  Copying HTML to the clipboard is a built-in feature of Microsoft Visual 
  Studio and Visual Assist X does not enhance the feature. The
  clipboard contains **only the default colors of the IDE**. Enhanced syntax
  colors are not placed in the clipboard.

So it seems like what you want cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is to make a final pdf, you can convert text file to pdf and combine your code pdf to your word pdf. You can try notepad++ for your default coloring your code.

Comment: It is not my ultimate goal